# I have a 93 f150 5L auto tranny w/OD electric 4x4, its slipping. I have a 91 f150 5L auto tranny w/OD manual 4x4 shift. Will 91 tranny work in the 93?

Tags: ford, automatic-transmission, manual-transmission, f-150, part-interchange

<I have a 93 f150 5L auto tranny w/od electric shift 4x4 gone bad.I have a good 91 f150 5L auto tranny w/od manual shift 4x4. Will 91 tranny work in the 93?>

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.